# how to set image view source dynamically?

Tags: android, json, api

So I have something like a rest API and when I call it, it gives me the sources of my images with Json objects.
I have the src for images in the server but I dont know how to use them.

```
 rule_op1.setImageResource("https://admin.webeskan.com/upload/lawgroup/"+law0);
```

where "https://admin.webeskan.com/upload/lawgroup/" is the same for all the images and law0 is one of the strings I get from the API (Json object)

Comment: use can use picasso or glide to load image from url

Comment: You should probably try Googling image loading libraries. There are a bunch of them these days. Glide, Picasso and Coil are the three libraries I most often come in contact with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Glide can be very helpful. It is very efficient to load images.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Add the following dependencies in your app gradle.

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  // Glide v4 uses this new annotation processor -- see https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

Add this line to load image

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("https://admin.webeskan.com/upload/lawgroup/"+law0)
    .override(300, 200)
    .into(rule_op1);
```

Comment: Tried build after adding dependency ?